# Problems with rigidbody2D in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I honestly can't figure out what's wrong with this code. I guess I'm still new at unity, would love to get some help.

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject objToSpawn;
    objToSpawn = new GameObject("Obstacle");
    objToSpawn.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    objToSpawn.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    objToSpawn.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    Rigidbody2D rigid;
    rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rigid.gravityScale = 0;
    rigid.isKinematic = true;
    pos = objToSpawn.transform.position;


}
```

When the program starts, the gravity scale is still 1 and isKinematic is still false. Why?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the `Rigidbody2D` on `objToSpawn`, or the object that this script is attached to?

Comment: Don't you happen to have an `Update` or `FixedUpdate` which modifies those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct. You should use a prefab and instantiate it when you have a complex object. I'll explain why the code you have doesn't work though too. your error is in the line

```
rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

This will get the `rigidBody2D` of the `GameObject` that the current script is attached to. I'm guessing what you meant to do was:

```
rigid = objToSpawn.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

Which will get the`rigidBody2D` that is on the object you just instantiated called `objToSpawn`.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to create a prefab then instantiate it. It would be a better way to create a new object than the one you are doing.  Go to unity documentation and check its  parameters.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask, but try to use the game development board if your question is more game oriented.